# Copy DOM element with its events in variable (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dom, replace, copy

I wanted to copy DOM element in variable, so I did this:

> var before=$("#someid").html();

Then my script does a bunch of stuff in this "someid" DOM and after that is completed I restored DOM like it was before:

> $("#someid").html(before);

This works ok but the problem is that I had some events in this DOM and those events can not be copied like this... So is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method can preserve both event handlers and element data. You can write:

```
var $before = $("#someid").clone(true);
```

Then later:

```
$("#someid").replaceWith($before);
```

Comment: woks perfect for me <3