# Unable to Clone HTML & Values into jQuery Datatables 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This question has been asked on a few occasions, for example:

[Store Cloned Element in Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171653/jquery-cloned-element-being-altered-in-variable)

[Copy DOM Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778166/copy-dom-element-with-its-events-in-variable-jquery)

However, I'm having issues selecting say `<div id="XYZ"></div>` and cloning it to a variable for the jQuery DataTable `fnStateSaveParams` to save. When the page refreshes it is then meant to reload the cloned object back into the HTML via `fnStateLoadParams`. I am trying to use `.clone()` over `.html()` because I also need the values stored within the dynamically generated textboxes.

If I'm not saving and loading via the Datatables plugin, then it works perfectly. As soon as I try calling code similar to the below then it ceases to work (please bare in mind I've tried a number of variations to the below code). Has anyone got any ideas or suggestions?

```
"fnStateSaveParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
    var clonedHtml= $("#XYZ").clone(true);
    oData.storedHtml = clonedHtml;
},
"fnStateLoadParams": function (oSettings, oData) {
    //$("#displayHtml").append(oData.storedHtml);
    //$("#displayHtml").html(oData.storedHtml);
    //$(oData.storedHtml).prependTo("#displayHtml")
}

<div id="XYZ">
    <div data-template="">
        <label class="bolder"></label>

        <div class="input-append">
            <div class="inline-block advancedSearchItem">
                <input type="text" id="test1" value="Test Scenario" />
            </div>

            <a href="#" data-id="" class="btn btn-small btn-danger removeField">
                <div class="hidden-phone">Remove</div>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-only hidden-tablet hidden-desktop"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The end scenario will be more complex, however the above is the simplest form of what I am trying to create. If you need more information, feel free to ask and I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way of utilising `.clone()` to grab all HTML and Text Box values. However, I did come up with a solution and the code below is for anyone who needs a reference point.

Using `.html()` (as most will know) will only copy the available HTML and ignore what is essentially 'placeholder' text within text fields. My solution though is to force the `value` into the HTML rather than being treated as 'placeholder' text, this allows it to be used again when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).on("click", "#advancedSearchButton", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // DO SOME STUFF HERE

    $("[data-value]").each(function(index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            fieldCount++;
            $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
        }
    });

    oTable.fnFilter("");
});

function loadData() {
    // ... ... ...
    "fnStateSaveParams": function(oSettings, oData) {
        oData.advancedSearchHtml = $("#addedSearchFields").html();
        oData.fieldCount = fieldCount;
        oData.isAdvancedSearch = isAdvancedSearch;
    },
    "fnStateLoadParams": function(oSettings, oData) {
        $("#addedSearchFields").html(oData.advancedSearchHtml);

        if (oData.isAdvancedSearch == true) {
            $("#collapseElement").removeClass("collapsed");
            $("#collapseIcon").removeClass().addClass("icon-chevron-up");
            $("#filter").hide();
        }

        isAdvancedSearch = oData.isAdvancedSearch;
        advancedSearchFields = oData.fieldCount;
    }
    // ... ... ...
}
```